# How to make express serve on '/' without index.html?

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

This is a server configuration code:

```
const app = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
  contentBase: '/public/', 
  proxy: {'/graphql': `http://localhost:${GRAPHQL_PORT}`},
  publicPath: '/js/', 
  stats: {colors: true}, 
});
// Serve static resources
app.use('/', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));
```

when the app runs, it's on localhost:3000/index.html , I want to render the app on localhost:3000/ . How can I achieve that? I am having this problem because without error, react router don't work in my code:

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Route exact path='/' component={App}/>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

and on localhost:3000/ this is my output:

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your index.html is in public folder and as you have already declared it as `static`, you can serve your App like

```
app.get('/', function(res){
     res.sendfile('public/index.html');
})
```

Then you can Access your React app with

```
http://localhost:3000/
```